# DATEDIF on a Range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an Excel table with 2 columns for Created Date and Closed Date. I'm trying to get a count of records within a certain range of lifetime values (lifetime = # days between Created and Closed Date).  So for example, how many records have a lifetime of 40+ days.

I can't modify the table to add new columns (I'm trying to do my calculation off in a separate sheet without modifying the main sheet with the data).

What I tried to do is this:

```
=COUNTIF(DATEDIF(MyTable[CreatedDate], MyTable[ClosedDate], "d"), "> 40")
```

That formula doesn't work, I believe for a couple of reasons: You can't pass ranges to DATEDIF, also DATEDIF returns a discrete value but COUNTIF expects a range.

It appears that what I'm trying to do obviously doesn't work on Ranges. Is there a way to do a DATEDIF between two Ranges, that then returns a new Range so that I can COUNTIF it?  Or some other way to accomplish my goal?

Some Sample Data (Lifetime is not an actual column in my table, just included here for convenience):

```
Created Date      Closed Date      Lifetime
9/20/2012         10/19/2012       29
9/20/2012         10/27/2012       37
9/20/2012         12/26/2012       97
9/20/2012         10/23/2012       33
9/20/2012         11/23/2012       64
10/19/2012        12/14/2012       56
```

Note: Every record will have a valid Created and Closed Date.

UPDATE: @pnuts suggested a formula that may or may not work:

```
=COUNTIF(MyTable[ClosedDate], ">"&MyTable[CreatedDate]+40)
```

I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but depending on what cells in my worksheet I put that formula in I get different results.  Here's a screenshot, every cell has an identical formula as shown in the formula bar.

[image]

If anybody wants to try it out in my sample Excel file, you can grab it here: [Sample Excel File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20949564/Lifetime%20Sample.xlsx)

Comment: What is the value of =average(MyTable[ClosedDate])-average(MyTable[CreatedDate])     Also, are there any open records in the mix, those not yet completed?

Comment: @zipzit - interesting, so your suggestion returned the right results.  But my question using AVERAGE was simplified a bit from my actual problem, give me a min and I'll update the question.

Comment: @pnuts - yes, my data does have times also, but I don't really care about them.  I didn't include it in my sample data in the question because I didn't realize it mattered.

Comment: Note for anybody coming late to this question, I updated the question significantly to reflect my real problem.

Comment: @pnuts if that would work it would be exactly what I want (you got me excited). When I try it, it gives a result of 0, and when I step through the evaluation it ends up like this: COUNTIF($E$9:$E$14, ">"&(#VALUE!)), I think the 2nd arg in COUNTIF expects a discrete value not a Range.  Even if I remove the +40 bit it's the same results.

Comment: @pnuts I tried it both on the same sheet, and on a diff sheet with the Sheet1! qualifier, and I get the same results.

Comment: I think I discovered something that is messing with my/our minds.  That formula works for me only if I put it in certain cells in my sheet, other cells returns 0.  I'm attaching an image to illustrate to my Q in a min.

Comment: ok, I understand why I'm seeing the weird behavior, it's evaluating the 2nd argument in the COUNTIF (the CreatedDate) to a single value that aligns with whatever cell the formula is in.  It's not treating it as a Range as we're hoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that @pnuts' formula works if you use it as an array formula, i.e. if you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A non-array formula you can use is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((Table1[Closed Date]-Table1[Created Date])>40)*1)
```

`Table1[Closed Date]-Table1[Created Date]` is the difference between dates and when you put `>40` after it, you will get a series of boolean (True/False) and the `*1` at the end converts the True to 1 and the False to 0. `SUMPRODUCT` adds them all up.

Comment: Ah, I have never seen this array formula thing before.  I'll have to read up on it, but you are correct, when I do pnuts formula with the curly braces it works (as does your SUMPRODUCT alternative)!  Huzzah!

Comment: @DylanSmith It's understandable, I too was a bit confused when I first stumbled on array formulas here :)

Comment: @pnuts It's okay, it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

`=SUM(IF((Table[ClosedDate])-(Table[CreatedDate])>=40,1,0))`

Comment: I'm not getting correct results with that, also it appears to suffer from the same problem that pnuts suggestion does, where it gives different results depending on what cell in my worksheet I put that formula in.

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter? You should see curly braces around your formula.

Comment: AHA!  I missed the ctrl/shift/enter part.