# Excel: Use AVERAGEIFS to calculate the average of a dynamic difference

Tags: excel

I have a table of account information including a creation date and a status field that can be "open" or "closed." My goal is, for any given day, calculate the average account age as of that day, including only accounts that existed at that point and which are still open. I am testing this with a column of all days from 1/1/2017 to 2/29/2024, and would like to have the average age for each day in that range.

I have figured out how to do a count of accounts that meet these criteria, but am having trouble figuring out how to leverage AVERAGEIFS on a date difference.
For the below example formula, here is the data formatting:

Column accts!B = Created date

Column accts!F = Closed or open status

Column A = range of dates from 2017-2024

Essentially my goal is this:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(DATEDIF(A3, accts!$B$2:$B$358,"D"), accts!$B$2:$B$358, "<="&A3, accts!$F$2:$F$358, "=open")
```

but the average range field does not do what I would have expected. A3 is the current date under consideration, and this formula would be applied for every row in the test date range.

Example data:

accts

| ID | CreatedDate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x01 | 1/1/2020 | open |
| x02 | 1/8/2020 | open |
| x03 | 1/15/2020 | open |
| x04 | 1/31/2020 | open |
| x05 | 2/15/2020 | closed |
| x06 | 2/28/2020 | closed |
| x07 | 2/28/2020 | open |
| x08 | 3/2/2020 | closed |
| x09 | 3/3/2020 | closed |
| x10 | 3/3/2020 | open |

dates and expected results

| Date | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 0 |
| 1/2/2020 | 1 |
| 1/3/2020 | 2 |
| ... |  |
| 2/1/2020 | 18.25 |
| 2/2/2020 | 19.25 |
| 2/3/2020 | 20.25 |
| ... |  |
| 3/6/2020 | 36.5 |
| 3/7/2020 | 37.5 |
| 3/8/2020 | 38.5 |

Comment: Post some sample data with expected output. Use **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** to create textual sample so that one can copy and past. Copy your sample from excel and directly paste in the link, it will create the table and then copy and paste it here by **[editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78084142/edit)** your post

Comment: Using your formula: `=AVERAGE(FILTER(IFERROR(DATEDIF(A3, accts!$B$2:$B$358,"D"),0), (accts!$B$2:$B$358<=A3)*(accts!$F$2:$F$358="open"),0))`

Comment: Shouldn't your data sample have some age info to calculate average properly?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995224/datedif-on-a-range-in-excel) can help